# SWRevealViewController Swipe/Tap gesture not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I've implemented `SWRevealViewController` according to the tutorials I've seen for a hamburger slide menu. Things are working great, except if I use the slide menu on a later page in the app, and then collapse it, and then go to an earlier page and try to use it, it will open, but no gestures will collapse it *unless* I navigate back to the page that last opened the menu. Then I can close it from there.

The code I'm using in the `viewDidLoad` of each `ViewController` is

```
let menuButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton?.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton?.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())

    }
```

Any ideas what's causing this/how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the code from `ViewDidLoad` and use it in `ViewDidAppear`.

`ViewDidLoad` runs only once, when `UIViewController` class is loading.

`ViewDidAppear` runs every time the `UIViewController` appears on screen.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Just tried it and it solved my problem exactly.